# Calculating and comparing lifetime risk

Tags: biostatistics, relative-risk, absolute-risk

Is the following calculation/approximation appropriate when calculating lifetime risk (?):

---

The lifetime risk of developing a disease or adverse event secondarily to a therapy or intervention was denoted as **Lifetime Risk (adverse event)** and calculated by:

Lifetime Risk (adverse event) = RR (intervention) * Lifetime Risk (general population)

where **"Lifetime Risk (general population)"** is the general lifetime risk of developing the disease or adverse event without being subject to the therapy or intervention, and **"RR (intervention)"** is the relative risk (RR) from previously published RR data (relating to the development of the questioned disease or adverse event to the intervention).

Or is the following equation better (?):

Lifetime Risk (adverse event) = [RR (intervention) - 1] * Lifetime Risk (general population) ???

Comment: What is your thinking behind your second equation? If, say, RR=1 (same risk in intervention group as among controls, it says that lifetime risk = 0 \times risk in general pop.  Can that be correct???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your first equation.  When you think about what RR (relative risk) means, it is the risk in the treatment group compared to the risk (probability of being affected) for the control group, where we take the control group as representative of the general population (that identification seems to be implicit in your question, even if it in general is doubtful).

As for why your second equation do not make sense, just look at what it says if RR=1!